# problems with android DataBinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I recently found something called databinding on android and it seemed very interesting, so I proceeded to implement it in one of my projects that I'm going to start. Everything works as it should when I do databinding in a textview but if I try to do it in an edittext the compiler generates an error. After that, I started to follow a tutorial on YouTube that seemed very good to me the way it teaches but although I followed all the steps he says, I have not made it work.

Can someone help me?

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="student2"
            type="com.juan97.prueba.ViewModel.Student2ViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@{student2.hint1}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@{student2.hint2}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

view

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        Student2ViewModel viewModel = new Student2ViewModel(new Student2("usuario", "contrasena"));

        activityMainBinding.setStudent(viewModel);

    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class Student2ViewModel {

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String hint1;
    private String hint2;

    public Student2ViewModel(Student2 student2) {

        this.hint1 = student2.hint1;
        this.hint2 = student2.hint2;

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getHint1() {
        return hint1;
    }

    public void setHint1(String hint1) {
        this.hint1 = hint1;
    }

    public String getHint2() {
        return hint2;
    }

    public void setHint2(String hint2) {
        this.hint2 = hint2;
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class Student2 {

    private String email;
    private String password;
    public String hint1;
    public String hint2;

    public Student2(String hint1, String hint2) {
        this.hint1 = hint1;
        this.hint2 = hint2;
    }

    public Student2() {

        email = null;
        password = null;
        hint1 = null;
        hint2 = null;

    }
}
```

build.gradle  module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.juan97.prueba"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    dataBinding {   <- this is the library that I need to use dataBinding
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

the compile error

error: cannot find symbol class ViewModel <-- this is what the console says

Class auto generated that give me the error:

```
import android.databinding.Bindable;
import android.databinding.DataBindingComponent;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.juan97.prueba.ViewModel;   <- error here, so everything that has viewModel contains an error

public abstract class ActivityMainBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
  @Bindable
  protected ViewModel.Student2ViewModel mStudent2; <- error here

  protected ActivityMainBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
      int _localFieldCount) {
    super(_bindingComponent, _root, _localFieldCount);
  }

  public abstract void setStudent2(@Nullable ViewModel.Student2ViewModel student2); <- error here

  @Nullable
  public ViewModel.Student2ViewModel getStudent2() { <- error here
    return mStudent2;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) {
    return inflate(inflater, root, attachToRoot, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
       @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
     return DataBindingUtil.<ActivityMainBinding>inflate(inflater, com.juan97.prueba.R.layout.activity_main, root, attachToRoot, component);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
  }

   @NonNull
  public static ActivityMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
    return DataBindingUtil.<ActivityMainBinding>inflate(inflater, com.juan97.prueba.R.layout.activity_main, null, false, component);
  }

  public static ActivityMainBinding bind(@NonNull View view) {
    return bind(view, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
  }

  public static ActivityMainBinding bind(@NonNull View view,
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
    return (ActivityMainBinding)bind(component, view, com.juan97.prueba.R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

**(UPDATE)**

In my project, as I wish to apply the MVVM pattern, I have a package for the model, a package for the view and a package for the viewModel. But recently I discovered that if I put all the classes in the main folder, outside the packages mentioned above, the compiler stops sending the error and the application compiles correctly. So, why does this happen and how can I do to continue using the classes within the packages mentioned above without generating the error that the compiler sends?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you find any solutions ? @juan

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1) Your xml needs to start and end with:

```
<layout>
 ...

</layout >
```

2) You need to add following lines inside your module's build.gradle:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the layout tag that was missing, I had it included only I do not know why I did not appear when I wrote the code here. In addition, the library that you suggest in the gradle also has it included in it, but the error keeps appearing in the self-generated class that ends in Binding. see the previous code.